# Does making an item slotless increase its price?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, pricing

In misreading [Fering's question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143515/48759) I thought he was asking if making his item slotless would increase the price. I thought that was worthy of its own question.

When crafting a magic item with the [craft wondrous item rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-item-creation/#) a GM may allow alterations to be made. If that alteration were to remove the slot requirement from an item, how much would it increase the price by?

For instance: a druid with the Craft Wondrous Item feat wants to make a slotless item with the same benefits at the Druid's Vestment. This item is normally costs 1,375gp to craft. What is the new crafting cost for the slotless version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the price increases as per the [Magic Item Gold Piece Values
chart](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-item-creation/#Magic_Item_Gold_Piece_Values).

> Special | Base Price | Example
>
> No space limitation<sup>3</sup> | Multiply entire cost by 2 |  Ioun stone
>
> ---
>
> <sup>3</sup> An item that does not take up one of the spaces on a body costs double.

So the end price of the druid's vestment would be 2750gp.

Comment: This could be improved by including that the cost of the example item would end up being 2750g